# Correlation and independenc of two random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variable.

Is it true that if $X$ and $Y$ are not correlation ( $ \mbox{corr}(X,Y) = 0$) then $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Comment: The statement is false in general. It is true only in special cases, such as when X and Y are jointly normal, i.e., have a bivariate normal distribution.

Comment: Ok. So when $X$ and $Y$ aren't correlation, what can we say about $EXY$ (if we know $EX$ and $EY$) ? Nothing?

Comment: Without loss of generality one may choose $EX=EY=0$. Assuming $X$ and $Y$ are non-trivial random variables (i.e., their variances are greater than zero...), zero correlation is equivalent to $E(XY)=0$.

Comment: But in my case $EX \neq 0$ and $EY \neq 0$.

Comment: Why $E(XY) = EX+EY - (EX)(EY) ?$ We have $E(X-EX)(Y-EY) = E(XY - XEY - YEX +(EX)(EY)) = E(XY) - (EX)(EY) = 0$ hence $E(XY)=(EX)(EY)$ .Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $X$ take on the values $-1$, $0$, and $1$, each with probability $\frac{1}{3}$.  Let $Y=X^2$.

Compute the covariance of $X$ and $Y$. You should get $0$.

Argue that $\Pr((X=0)\cap (Y=0))\ne \Pr(X=0)\Pr(Y=0)$.

**Remark:** You can use the same basic idea to "roll your own." It is convenient to use an $X$ with symmetric distribution about $0$, to make the computation of $E(X)$ and $E(XY)$ easy. You might want to try the same thing with $X$ having (continuous) uniform distribution on $[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

the correlation function is measure of of degree of linearity between X and Y so
value near O indicates that such linearity is absent . 
and is true if corr(X,Y)=0 due to:
cov(X,Y)=0 <=>E[XY]-E[X]E[Y] =0
however X and Y are clearly independent

Comment: For some basic information about writing maths at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latexhelp/notation).

Comment: Zero correlation (or covariance) does **not** imply independence. As you point out, covariance is a statement about a linear relationship between X and Y. An absence of a *linear* relationship doesn't imply the absence of *any* relationship...